# How to remove Ionic Framework tabs bar+ buttons and simplify routing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I have an existing app with tabs bar and buttons at the bottom. 
I hope to remove tabs completely and simplify the routing. Is it possible?

Im not looking for css or ionic appearence changes like suggested **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991852/how-do-i-hide-the-tabs-in-ionic-framework)**. This merely hides the bar but routing isnt simplified.

**My current routing:**

```
.state('tab', {
  url: '/tab',       //anyway to remove this?
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
})
.state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
  controller: 'AuthCtrl'
})
.state('tab.posts', {    //ideally no more tabs.something
  url: '/posts',
  views: {
    'tab-posts': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-posts.html',
      controller: 'PostsCtrl'}}
})
.state('tab.newpost', {
  url: '/newpost',
  views: {
    'tab-posts': {    
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-newpost.html',
      controller: 'NavCtrl'}}
})
.state('tab.posts.view', {
  url: '/posts/:postId',          
  views: {
    'tab-posts@tab': {    
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-showpost.html',
      controller: 'PostViewCtrl'}}
})
```

I hope to simplify routing by removing the tab abstract state. Cos right now, it can get rather confusing with the view names and all.

I removed tabs state but app returned blank. Same for deleting the html file URL line.

When I revamped the naming convention, the program no longer works (blank screen) but yet devtools doesnt throw any errors.

Comment: how do you want to handle the routing? That is pretty critical piece of information that is missing

Comment: @AaronSaunders I did mention it just after the pasted codes. I hope to remove the tab state, and hopefully reduce the other states too. For example tab.posts.view to just posts.view. Please feel free to shoot more questions. :)