# Concerns about ionic navigate out of tab but keep history, transition and back button

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

Navigate to **Friends** tab then click "G.I. Joe".
Back button, transition and history are working as expected.

[this sample](http://embed.plnkr.co/qYMCrt/preview)

But I want it to hide the tabs while entering the details page, so I made the view replace the main nav, like this:

```
.state('tab.friend-detail', {
  url: '/friend/:friendId',
  views: {
    '@': {
      templateUrl: 'friend-detail.html',
      controller: 'FriendDetailCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

But now Back button, transition and history stop working.

[expected to work](http://embed.plnkr.co/OHbJwfguUhtW1kU5uO3Y/preview)

[Here is just what I want](http://istarter.io/ionic-starter-messenger/#/tab/activities)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [expected to work](http://embed.plnkr.co/SxqzZp/preview).

#### How ?

- I added the `tabs-item-hide` class for the `<ion-tabs>` tag with `ng-class`.
- Then use `$rootScope` as a flag inside every controller to detect if current view wants to show or not the tabs.

*Maybe my solution is not good enough, but I think it will help you.*

#### Cons?

- You have to put the `$rootScope` flag (in my example is : `$rootScope.data.hideTabs`) in every controller that you want the tabs to show or hide.
- Everything inside `<ion-content>` won't be shown.

But you can modify it anytime for better usage, for example you can create a factory to manage it.

***P/S:*** I have inspired from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991852/how-do-i-hide-the-tabs-in-ionic-framework)

Comment: Your solution seems to hide every content within the `ion-content` as well :-(

Comment: Did you try that? It won't touch anything else except the tabs bar.

Comment: Yes, I edited yor Plunker and simpy put `<p>test</p>` in the ion-content block.

Comment: Ok, but if I change to this `<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top" ng-hide="data.hideTabs">` it still hide all the content.

Comment: The docs said that : To hide the tabbar but still show the content, add the tabs-item-hide class. I have no idea about the content.

Comment: This sounds really trick. I was expecting something more like this: http://istarter.io/ionic-starter-messenger/#/tab/activities . See that the tab is not hide but animated like a normal view. (like whatsapp/hangout)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your tabs.html:

```
<!-- 
  Create tabs with an icon and label, using the tabs-positive style. 
  Each tab's child <ion-nav-view> directive will have its own 
  navigation history that also transitions its views in and out.
-->
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top">


  <!-- Pets Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Dashboard" icon="icon ion-home" href="#/tab/dash">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>


  <!-- Adopt Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Friends" icon="icon ion-heart" href="#/tab/friends">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-friends"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>


  <!-- About Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Account" icon="icon ion-gear-b" href="#/tab/account">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>


</ion-tabs>
```

it already states at the top that each `ion-nav-view` has its own navigation history.
So if you load the details html in another view you'll lose history information. Hence there's no backbutton.

However, look at [this proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991852/how-do-i-hide-the-tabs-in-ionic-framework) witch uses a custom directive to achieve what you want.