# ionic hide-tabs not work on nested view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Followed by the article [How do I hide the tabs in Ionic Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991852/how-do-i-hide-the-tabs-in-ionic-framework), the hide-tabs directive works fine.
But it has some problem when nested view.

As you can see in the codepen http://codepen.io/WilsonFpz/pen/MaxaQR, when the user navigate from home->level1->level2,
the level2`s tabs show again, but the $root.hideTabs is false as printing out.

```
var module = angular.module('app.directives', []);
module.directive('hideTabs', function($rootScope) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
        scope.$watch(attributes.hideTabs, function(value){
            $rootScope.hideTabs = value;
        });

        scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
            $rootScope.hideTabs = false;
        });
    }
};
});
```

Please give me some hints. Thanks.